# Nextjs - 'ReferrenceError: document is not defined' when using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get Bootstrap tooltips working in my NextJS project. I've got other parts of bootstrap working that require JS but tooltips need a bit of JS that uses `document.querySelectorAll` and this is where I am having the issue. The code from bootstrap's docs is:

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

I have tried all the solutions I've come across, such as wrapping the code in `typeof document !== "undefined` and using `useEffect` but it seems that during SSR it's still trying to run this code. Have I written the `useEffect` incorrectly or is something else going on here? Here is my `useEffect` code:

```
const Page = (props: any) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
  }, []);

  return (...
```

I am using the rest of bootstrap in NextJS without issues so please don't just recommend using react-bootstrap, I had a lot of issues with that.

Thanks in advance!

Here are the versions using `typeof document !== "undefined":

```
if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
    let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    let tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

With some help from the comments, it's working now inside the useEffect (as in it's not failing on my code). However, it's now giving the same error for code within `bootstrap.js`. The error is as follows:

> error - ReferenceError: document is not defined
> at enableDismissTrigger (G:\Projects\nextjs\aaip-ts-bs-app\aaip-ts-bs\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:761:21)
> at G:\Projects\nextjs\aaip-ts-bs-app\aaip-ts-bs\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:856:3
> at G:\Projects\nextjs\aaip-ts-bs-app\aaip-ts-bs\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:7:83
> at Object. (G:\Projects\nextjs\aaip-ts-bs-app\aaip-ts-bs\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:10:3)

So I guess it's the same error but when the server is trying to run some code within bootstrap.js?

I've tried to use the `next/dynamic` solution in this medium post: [Third solution at the bottom of the post](https://www.webtutpro.com/solve-document-is-not-defined-errors-in-next-js-26fea778b868) but I'm not really sure how to import `Tooltip` that way and use it inside the `useEffect` hook. The article uses the example of a component to be rendered on the client, which isn't the setup in this case.

Here is the offending method inside bootstrap's util/component-functions.js file if it's helpful:

```
/**
   * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Bootstrap (v5.1.3): util/component-functions.js
   * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
   * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  const enableDismissTrigger = (component, method = 'hide') => {
    const clickEvent = `click.dismiss${component.EVENT_KEY}`;
    const name = component.NAME;
    EventHandler.on(document, clickEvent, `[data-bs-dismiss="${name}"]`, function (event) {
      if (['A', 'AREA'].includes(this.tagName)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      if (isDisabled(this)) {
        return;
      }

      const target = getElementFromSelector(this) || this.closest(`.${name}`);
      const instance = component.getOrCreateInstance(target); // Method argument is left, for Alert and only, as it doesn't implement the 'hide' method

      instance[method]();
    });
  };
```

As you can see, on the 4th line it tries to reference `document`.

Thanks to @juliomalves in the comments for helping me sort the original issue and thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with the new one!

Comment: Post the code sample of where you have used `typeof document !== "undefined`

Comment: Well it's the same as the above but instead of the bootstrap code being inside a useEffect call it's inside if(typeof document !== "undefined) {... but I'll add it to the main question body if that helps.

Comment: Calling `document.querySelectorAll` inside a `useEffect` will not trigger the error you're seeing. The issue most likely comes from something else. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Ah okay, it's getting past that point now even though I swear my code hasn't changed! Maybe I just needed to restart the debugger instance or something or maybe I had a typo somewhere. Thanks for the help. I don't get 'document is not defined' inside the useEffect anymore but I'm now getting that error inside the booststrap.js library. I have tried using next/dynamic but can't seem to get it to work, I've added this issue as an update to the question, any chance you can help?

Comment: I've finally got it sorted, I don't know if it's good practice but I'll post it as an answer just in case anyone else has the same issue. Thanks for the help though @juliomalves

Comment: Curious, if you are going to publish your working solution.. thanks

Comment: Hi, I did as an answer in December, should be visible below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my initial problem has already been answered in the "UPDATE" section of the question.

If anyone has the same issue with the second part (references to document in bootstrap.js) then here is the solution I've got. I'm not saying this is good practice but it compiles and works as expected for my project (I now have tooltips!)

So in _app.js where I was originally importing bootstrap inside `useEffect` I have replaced that with the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadBootstrap() {
      const bootstrap = await import("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");

      var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
      var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
      });
    }

    loadBootstrap();
  }, []);
```

So from what I gather, because we're calling some parts of the bootstrap library directly, we need to make sure this is being done client-side only, and so it needs to happen in the `useEffect` hook. To be able to target `bootstrap.Tooltip` we need to import `bootstrap` inside the `useEffect` hook and assign it to a variable. This is all put in an async func that is declared and then called in the `useEffect` hook.

If you need any other bootstrap js code that directly or indirectly refers to `document` (which most of it does), then that will have to go in here too.

And if you only need it on a specific page rather than _app.js then you can just move it there.

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution! The node_modules import didn't exactly work for me so instead I had to just import bootstrap const bootstrap = await import('bootstrap'); but I never would have thought to import it inside the function without your suggestion. This solves a big issue for me, thanks!!

Comment: @ChristineTreacy Glad it worked for you! I'm not saying this is good practice but I really have no idea so there might be a better solution out there but it's been working for the last couple of years so I haven't gone back to it!